# For loop for finding concordance is taking a lot of time for large data. (14+hrs for 0.15mln * 36k rows)

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, for-loop

I am running this code in python3.5 to find Concordance (logistic regression).

```
for i in (ones2.index):
    for j in (zeros2.index):
      pairs_tested = pairs_tested+1
      if(ones2.iloc[i,1] > zeros2.iloc[j,1]):
          conc = conc+1
      elif(ones2.iloc[i,1]==zeros2.iloc[j,1]):
          ties = ties+1
      else:
          disc = disc+1

  # Calculate concordance, discordance and ties
concordance = conc/pairs_tested
discordance = disc/pairs_tested
ties_perc = ties/pairs_tested

print("Concordance = %r", concordance)
print("Discordance = %r", discordance)
print("Tied = %r", ties_perc)
print("Pairs = %r", pairs_tested)
```

There are 0.15mln rows in **zeros2(panda dataframe)** and 36k rows in **ones2(panda dataframe)**. Both the tables have two variables

**[i]** Responders (Responder0 = 0 in zeros2 and Responders1 = 1 in ones2).

**[ii]** Probabilities (prob0 in zeros2 and prob1 in ones2).

**My question is:** The for loop has taken 12hours and still running at the time when this question is being asked. Need help. how to perform this operation faster. I am running this on a windows 64bit machine with 8GB RAM.

Comment: Please give runnable code (eg. add dummy data, so it can actually be run).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is doing 5.4 billion calculations due to the two for loops (0.15 mil * 36k):

I would do something like this: (Thanks to @Leon for helping me make this answer better)

```
from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right

zeros_list = sorted([zeros2.iloc[j,1] for j in zeros2.index])
zeros2_length = len(zeros2_list)

for i in ones2.index:
    cur_disc = bisect_left(zeros2_list, ones2.iloc[i,1])
    cur_ties = bisect_right(zeros2_list, ones2.iloc[i,1]) - cur_disc
    disc += cur_disc
    ties += cur_ties
    conc += zeros2_length - cur_ties - cur_disc

pairs_tested = zeros2_length * len(ones2.index)

concordance = conc/pairs_tested
discordance = disc/pairs_tested
ties_perc = ties/pairs_tested

print("Concordance = %r", concordance)
print("Discordance = %r", discordance)
print("Tied = %r", ties_perc)
print("Pairs = %r", pairs_tested
```

Or, the other way round, like this:

```
zeros_list = sorted([zeros2.iloc[j,1] for j in zeros2.index])
ones2_list = sorted([ones2.iloc[i,1] for i in ones2.index])
zeros2_length = len(zeros2_list)
ones2_length = len(ones2_list)

for i in zeros2.index:
    cur_conc = bisect_left(ones2_list, zeros2.iloc[i,1])
    cur_ties = bisect_right(ones2_list, zeros2.iloc[i,1]) - cur_conc
    conc += cur_conc
    ties += cur_ties
    disc += ones2_length - cur_ties - cur_conc

# We could also achieve the above like this too:
# for i in zeros2_list:
#    cur_conc = bisect_left(ones2_list, i)
#    cur_ties = bisect_right(ones2_list, i) - cur_conc
#    conc += cur_conc
#    ties += cur_ties
#    disc += ones2_length - cur_ties - cur_conc

pairs_tested = zeros2_length * ones2_length

concordance = conc/pairs_tested
discordance = disc/pairs_tested
ties_perc = ties/pairs_tested

print("Concordance = %r", concordance)
print("Discordance = %r", discordance)
print("Tied = %r", ties_perc)
print("Pairs = %r", pairs_tested
```

Comment: Why don't you take advantage of the "sortedness" of `zeros2_list` for the calculation of `disc`? In C++ I would use `std::lower_bound` for that.

Comment: `bisect_right` in Python does that - included it in the edit.

Comment: Better use `bisect_left`. `disc += bisect_left(zeros2_list, ones2.iloc[i,1])` will work correctly for both `ties==0` and `ties!=0`

Comment: Also you can count `ties` in O(log(N)) time instead of O(N) as follows: `ties = bisect_right(zeros2_list, ones2.iloc[i,1]) - bisect_left(zeros2_list, ones2.iloc[i,1])`

Comment: Yep. +1. That would make life easier without the if condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
Probability = model.predict_proba(data[predictors])
Probability1 = pd.DataFrame(Probability)
Probability1.columns = ['Prob_LoanStatus_0','Prob_LoanStatus_1']
TruthTable = pd.merge(data[[outcome]], Probability1[['Prob_LoanStatus_1']], how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)
zeros = TruthTable[(TruthTable['Loan_Status']==0)].reset_index().drop(['index'], axis = 1)
ones = TruthTable[(TruthTable['Loan_Status']==1)].reset_index().drop(['index'], axis = 1)

from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right

zeros_list = sorted([zeros.iloc[j,1] for j in zeros.index])
zeros_length = len(zeros_list)
disc = 0
ties = 0
conc = 0
for i in ones.index:
    cur_conc = bisect_left(zeros_list, ones.iloc[i,1])
    cur_ties = bisect_right(zeros_list, ones.iloc[i,1]) - cur_conc
    conc += cur_conc
    ties += cur_ties
pairs_tested = zeros_length * len(ones.index)
disc = pairs_tested - conc - ties

print("Pairs = ", pairs_tested)
print("Conc = ", conc)
print("Disc = ", disc)
print("Tied = ", ties)
concordance = conc/pairs_tested
discordance = disc/pairs_tested
ties_perc = ties/pairs_tested

print("Concordance = %r", concordance)
print("Discordance = %r", discordance)
print("Tied = %r", ties_perc)
```

I followed the reply of Sreyantha Chary which was elegant, but the concordance percentage and discordance percentage was mixed up in the first part of the answer.